# Destroying div after few seconds mixed with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to destroy div after few seconds after creating it. At the moment i'm using this

```
function info ( $s ) {
    return ( $s ? '<div class="info">'.$s.'</div><script type="text/javascript">$(".info").delay(3200).fadeOut(300);</script>' : false );
}
```

The problem is that doesn't work at all. I'm not good in JS at all, so I can't fix it by my own.
Thanks for advices and help.

Comment: Div is showing up, but it doesn't disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost fine.

Your problem is, that your `<script>` tag will be executed before the DOM is ready.

You need to make sure that the DOM is ready before you access it. ([reference](https://api.jquery.com/ready/))

```
function info ( $s ) {
    return ( $s ? '<div class="info">'.$s.'</div><script type="text/javascript">$(function(){$(".info").delay(3200).fadeOut(300);});</script>' : false );
}
```

So what I did is putting `$(function(){ /* ... */ });` around your code.

Comment: Open the dev console `F12` and post your error. jQuery is probably missing.

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: Yep. You are using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (the `$` syntax). This is a JavaScript library which makes JS much simpler. You need to include it to use it :-) You can include it over their [CDN](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js) or download it and include it. https://jquery.com/download/

Comment: You can add a `.remove()` in the callback of your `.fadeOut()`: `.fadeOut(300, function(){$(this).remove();});` or if you only wanna remove it just replace the `fadeOut` with `remove`